# Error al ejecutar el archivo JAR tras empaquetar

Tags: javafx

Estoy usando IntelliJ IDEA, con javaFX diseñe como proyecto personal la creación de una calculadora, y funciona, al ejecutar el código funciona sim problemas, es proyecto está estructurado con maven, al empaquetar el proyecto se genera el archivo JAR sin problemas, al intentar ejecutarlo con java -jar calculadora.jar me sale este mensaje:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.pruebacomponentes.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

no he encontrado la razón, probé cambiando algunas configuraciones del POM pero no ha cambiado el error

Comment: Posiblemente el jar no corre en la misma JVM que la de IntelliJ. Dependiendo de tu sistema operativo y de lo que regrese `java -version` habría que ajustar el entorno de ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se empaqueta y usas maven lo ideal seria ejecutar estos comandos CLEAR, COMPILE, PACKAGE en ese orden. La otra seria hacer el Build con Dependencias para que te pueda generar todo con las librerias.

[image: Comandos maven]

Y a traves del plugin de en el pom.xml puedes asignar la clase principal de ejecucion para evitar un MANIFEST vacio o sin las configuraciones adecuadas. Te dejo un ejemplo de uno funcional
[image: Plugins]